# ProgressDialog в JavaFX без Worker'а

Tags: java, javafx, rxjava

Здравствуйте.

Возникла такая проблема: не могу найти `ProgressDialog` (или `LoadingDialog`, кому как удобнее такое называть) для `JavaFX`. Для обычных `Task'ов` я пользовался библиотекой `org.controlsfx`, а точнее - `dialog.ProgressDialog` из нее. И мне все устраивало. Но недавно начал разбираться с `RxJava` и я застрял на этом моменте. Т.к. `Observer` никак не наследуется от `Task`, то задать для него `ProgressDialog` не получится. А запускается `Dialog` только если ему явно указать на необходимый `Task`, по окончание которого окно автоматически закрывается.

Пробовал делать костыли и создавал пустой `Task` для него. Не помогло. Запускается он нормально, однако методом `progressDialog.close()` он не останавливается. В стандартных `Alert'ах` в Java 8 никаких подобных окон я не нашел, а писать собственное, придумывая велосипеды, честно говоря, не очень хочется.

Возможно, кто-то уже сталкивался с таким вопрос. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: а как вы используете RxJava? для каких целей? добавьте фрагмент кода.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я посчитал, что код в данном случае не нужен. Использую я RxJava для обработки данных в других потоках. И я бы хотел, чтобы во время работы потока на экране была заглушка, уведомляющая об этом. Я пробовал делать только для потока, где нет `ProgressBar'а`, как такового, на хотелось бы, чтобы была возможность его использования.

Comment: как вы получаете информацию о прогрессе при обработке данных?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman у меня на вход подается список, я его разделяю оператором `flatMapIterable` и на каждый из получившихся `Observable` вешаю `doOnNext`, в котором инкрементирую прогресс. Точнее, так у меня происходит в Android приложении. А вот в десктопном JavaFX приложении столкнулся с отсутствием нормальных диалогов.

Comment: без кода мне понятно. диалоги в FX есть.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman мне кажется, мы идем немного не в ту сторону. Ведь какая разница, какой у меня код, если мне нужно просто диалоговое окно с прогресс-баром. Но если это действительно как-то поможет в продвижении, то вот ссылка на Gist того, как это сделано у меня в Android: https://gist.github.com/ahgpoug/86a889f283135ebbe4000f860ea93bc7

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, раз Вы утверждаете, что в JavaFX все-таки есть нормальные диалоги, возможно, можете посоветовать все-таки `ProgressDialog` с ручным управлением прогресс-баром?